# how to add an event subscriber when the user reaches the login form

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I am new on Drupal 8 , I have implemented a hook 'hook_form_alter' in my module to add a new field to the login form , but now I want to handle it with the event , I want to trigger an event when the user reaches the login form and then add this field using event not a hook.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do it ?

This is the hook

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form' ) {
    // Add placeholders.
    $form['condition'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#options' => t('Enable'),
      '#title' => t('J’accepte les conditions'),
      '#required' => true,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense (event). hook_form_alter is perfect. What's the problem with it?

Comment: there is no problem , but i want to implement it by the event , because in drupal 8 all the hooks was converted to events i think  , it's just like an exercise

Comment: This still needs work in core, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2402445

Comment: that means it's not yet exist in the core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not with core alone. D8 doesn't have a form-alter event.

D8 added events as an alternative to some D7 hooks but didn't fully replace all the hooks available. Replacing all hooks was [mooted for a D10 goal](https://youtu.be/yMabmAMulEE?t=2168) but didn't make the cut.

As such, the only way to do this modify core functionality like:

- Patch core (see issue comment) to add form-alter events.
- Do something like [Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher) which wraps custom form-alter events around a `hook_form_alter` handler.

Then add an event subscriber for it.